# How to load initial data in H2 when using flyway on spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2, flyway

I'm creating a spring boot application using Flyway to migration and want to use a memory database for development profile, but the problem is that data is lost every time I restart application. So I need to insert some data when my application start in development profile. I tried to put a file called `data.sql` on src/main/resource to spring load it when application starts but it doesnt work (It didnt run the script). I tried to put `INIT=runscript from 'classpath:data.sql'` in the h2 url but it tries to run it before Flyway migration execution so the tables doesnt exist yet. Can anyone give me an other way to do it?

My application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IFEXISTS=FALSE
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  flyway:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool) , you can create a dev profile and have customized flyway `pring.flyway.locations`  and run scripts when that profile is active . You can have the initialisation script as part of migration folder. [example](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-flyway-example/tree/master/src/main/resources/db/migration).

Comment: Also there is a [data migration property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-migration-properties) `spring.flyway.init-sqls` that looks might help. Never tried data migration, hence posting as comment ,hope it helps.

Comment: @R.G It works. I configured two spring.flyway.locations on my dev profile, one with my load data. Thanks

Comment: Great ! Can I add that as the answer and this question can be closed ?

Comment: Yes, It solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool) ,  a profile-specific customised flyway `spring.flyway.locations` can be configured. The profile-specific scripts runs when that profile is active . So a dev profile configured will work on this requirement.

The initialisation script can be placed as part of migration folder which will run and populate the db.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-flyway-example/tree/master/src/main/resources/db/migration)

Answer (score -1):

i have the same probleme to fix it, i added this configuration :
[image]

For me the configuraton tyou need to add to fix INSERT by flyway is :
`ddl-auto: none`

because jpa try to update database after flyway it's weird but it's work for me

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)

Comment: you shoud add insert data to dev/migration, spring will apply dev/migration scripts only for in my case "review" profile.