# Create new schema using Flyway from Java code

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

We have introduced Flyway inside the codebase. Previously, we have the Postgres function stored in the public schema and we use that to replicate the tenant schema to create a new schema that has the same structure as the tenant schema. The repo code is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface TenantRepository extends JpaRepository<Tenant, UUID> {

        @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT clone_schema(:defaultSchema,:newSchema,:isCopyData);")
    String callCloneSchema(@Param("defaultSchema") String defaultSchema, @Param("newSchema") String newSchema,@Param("isCopyData") boolean isCopyData);
}
```

I would like to delete these functions and want to create a new schema using the Flyway. Does Flyway offer such a possibility?

Comment: Does this answer help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239471/4214241

Comment: @R.G  It doesn't, I want to create a new schema runtime using Flyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps used to manually trigger Flyway migration with individual schemas:

**1. Disable "auto migration"**

By default, Spring boot would like to automatically run the Flyway SQL scripts. So you have to disable this "auto migration" (see [4.3. in this Blog](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway#3-empty-flywaymigrationstrategy)). Here, this is done in the "Spring Boot main class":

```
@SpringBootApplication                                        
public class FooApplication {                                 
                                                              
    public static void main(String[] args) {                  
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);    
    }                                                         
                                                              
    @Bean                                                     
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> {                                    
            // do nothing                                     
        };                                                    
    }                                                         
                                                              
}
```

**2. Manually migration**

To automatically do migration using different schemas, this would be one solution:

- inject (the default) `Flyway` instance
- duplicate the configuration but overwrite the schemas to be used
- trigger the migration

*Example code: Trigger of the migration via a GET request (the SQL files are under `src/main/resources/db/migration/V#_#_#__xyz.sql`)*

```
@Controller                                                               
public class FooController {                                              
                                                                          
    @Autowired                                                            
    Flyway flyway;                                                        
                                                                          
    @GetMapping("foo")                                                    
    public ResponseEntity<?> foo(@RequestParam("schema") String schema) { 
        Flyway.configure()                                                
                // apply/use the default (Spring) flyway configiration    
                .configuration(flyway.getConfiguration())                 
                // use the passed schema                                  
                .schemas(schema)                                          
                .defaultSchema(schema)                                    
                // get a Flyway instance                                  
                .load()                                                   
                // run the migration                                      
                .migrate();                                               
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();                        
    }                                                                     
                                                                          
}
```